# What does "God's children" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Could its meaning related to Christian culture? [Barack Obama](http://www.breitbart.com/big-government/2015/06/22/obama-at-wh-dinner-koran-teaches-us-we-are-one-family/) said it in Ramadan dinner, as a speech he refers people.

Comment: All of humanity:  we are all God's children.

Comment: Could its meaning related to christian culture.

Comment: deadrat may be right depending on your beliefs (or rather the beliefs of the person who wrote this). However:- It's not just  policy that requires so many words. We need context in order to give a good answer to your question. Firstly which religion are you discussing? Where did you find this expression? Who said it, what else were they saying? What is the surrounding text? Do you have a link?

Comment: Barack obama said it in ramadan dinner,as a speech he refers people.finally which religion , who knows obama's religion? It is solely another discussion.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to thanks chasly from UK for your illumination

Comment: @user145278 I doubt the concept of humanity's common spiritual parenthood is unique to Christianity, but the concept is closely entwined with the central doctrine of Christianity, namely divine filiation -- the worship of Jesus Christ as the son of God and the implication of that dogma for believers and nonbelievers.  There isn't a "Christian culture" any more than there is a single Christian religion.  There are dozens of denominations in the US alone.  I think it's safe to say that most believe that we are all God's children but some of us are going to hell.

Comment: I don't imagine Obama just said it out of context. Did he say for example, "We are all God's children"? Do you have any more of the text. Can we listen to it online?

Comment: Please wait i am searching

Comment: http://www.breitbart.com/big-government/2015/06/22/obama-at-wh-dinner-koran-teaches-us-we-are-one-family/

Comment: Several religions (pretty much all the monotheistic ones) consider all humans to be, in essence, the "children of God".  By referring to "God's children" a speaker/writer emphasizes the fact that we are all "brothers", regardless of the finer points of religion and nationality.

Comment: Let's close this question and move on. Come on guys. This question is off-topic.

Comment: @SvenYargs This question shoud have been closed right after it was posted. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster has not provided any context (in the question itself) to help clarify what is being asked or any summary of the results of his or her research into the question. For future reference, the minimum character count requirement for questions exists to encourage askers to include such context and research, not to make them supplement a skeletal question with meaningless filler.

Comment: At first my question was off-topic but then we cleared the question.i think some people dont want to critize the meaning so these people dont have to. We just think,discuss, critize and answer

Comment: Meaning isn't simple matter.it is also about philosophy of language. I think it is the main problem about what we discuss.

Comment: How do "children of the devil" (also known as "spawn of satan") figure in?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that you're reading something Barack Obama said.  At this year's Iftar dinner, Obama [said](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2015/06/23/remarks-president-2015-iftar-dinner)

> The Quran teaches that **God’s children** should tread gently upon the
>   earth and, when confronted by ignorance, reply “peace.”  In honoring
>   these familiar values together -- of peace and charity and forgiveness
>   -- we affirm that, whatever our faith, we’re **all one family**.

Not quite the exact phrasing, but [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2010/08/13/remarks-president-iftar-dinner) are the President's remarks in 2010:

> Here at the White House, we have a tradition of hosting iftars that
>   goes back several years, just as we host Christmas parties and seders
>   and Diwali celebrations.  And these events celebrate the role of faith
>   in the lives of the American people. They remind us of the basic truth
>   that **we are all children of God**, and we all draw strength and a sense
>   of purpose from our beliefs.

This trope isn't restricted to messages to Muslims.  [Here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2015/09/23/remarks-president-obama-and-his-holiness-pope-francis-arrival-ceremony) is the President clearly-inclusive statement during the Pope's recent visit:

... [H]ere in the United States, we cherish our religious liberty, but around the world, at this very moment, **children of God**, including Christians, are targeted and even killed because of their faith.

Barach Obama is a professed Christian.  Before he was elected President, he was a member of the Trinity United Church of Christ, a Chicago church affiliated with the Christian denomination the United Church of Christ.

Comment: If he says, "...children of God, including Christians..." then there is an implication that some people aren't children of God. So I think he means 'the people who believe in the God that I (Obama) believe in or an approximation to that god."  In other words he seems to be saying 'children of God' are those people who believe in a god whose authority Obama  recognises"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Please lie down and don't operate heavy machinery for a while.

Comment: The jokes are fine but is there a serious point in there somewhere? We're supposed to be answering what 'God's children' means in that context, not taking part in a theological debate.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  The OP read a statement from Obama that included the phrase "children of God" and wanted to know what it meant.  Is there something unclear about the answer?  'Cause if you tell me, perhaps I can fix it.  Nothing I've said is part of a "theological debate," which would be about whether there is a God and if so, are we really all his children.

Comment: I wasn't criticising as such. I thought you hadn't answered explicitly what you thought the phrase meant. Maybe you need to incorporate your comment. If we read the quotes you provide then we can conclude from the first that only people of ***faith*** belong to God's family. From the second we see that Americans (with faith?) are children of God.  Obama says nothing about, for example Buddhists or Hindus (or atheists) for example so my conclusion from the context (not from my personal beliefs) is that probably Obama means believers in the Abrahamic god (and therefore not everyone in the world)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I don't mind criticism as such, and I see your point.  I just don't agree with it.  These statements are all made on occasions having to do with religion and go out of their way to include others beyond a particular religion. The 1st Amendment to the US Constitution governs the context of religion in American civic life.  The President is a secular leader, unlike say, the Queen of England, Fidei Defensor.  When a President says "we" in these anodyne statements,  he means everyone.

Comment: I don't think that a *secular* leader has any authority to make religious pronouncements about who is a child of God. Nor do I think he has the right to include those who don't want to be included (atheists for example). Therefore I am not convinced by your argument (or Obama's).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK This is about what someone (here the President of the United States) means when he uses the phrase "children of God."   This is independent of his authority to make religious pronouncements or whether others accept his statements.  The President has no coercive authority ex officio in this matter, but he doesn't need any to speak.  Nor does he need anyone else's permission.

Comment: You are stating *your* belief about what the President means. Without consulting him personally you cannot know. I based my comment  on the provided context. That's all. By the way I made a comment expressing my opinion. You provided an answer giving yours. We are both entitled to do that. I don't think we will resolve our differences by a continued discussion here, nor should we. It is enough to state them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30949/discussion-between-deadrat-and-chasly-from-uk).

Answer (score 1):

Reference to the "sons of god" can be found in the old testament, Genesis 6:2 :

> "And *the sons of the Elohim* saw the daughters of the adam that they
> were good (beautiful); and they took to them wives whomsoever they
> chose".
>
> Of the sons of the Elohim there are three principal interpretations:
>
> - that of the Targums and the chief Jewish expositors, nobles and men of high rank,
> - that they were angels,
> - that they were the Sethites, from the lineage of seth. Captivated by the beauty of women of Cain descendance, they got married and universal corruption soon ensued.

However, the "children of gods" can be found in its modern Christian acceptance in many verses of the new testament. For example, in John 3:2
it is written:

> Beloved, we are God's children now.

From a religious point of view, all humans can be considered as "children of gods", as precedently mentionned by @HotLicks.

Comment: Yes, it is the answer to the question.